# Does NHibernate intergrate well with Microsoft Sync Framework?

Tags: nhibernate, microsoft-sync-framework

We are wanting to use both NHibernate and Microsoft Sync Framework - has anyone had experience combining these two frameworks?

Thanks,

Ashley

Comment: I've had enough pain with MSF alone. : )

Doesn't it defy the purpose of MSF to use with an ORM? MSF itself is a data access framework; with what comes out of the box it would presumably require much less effort to configure a sync provider for the underlying database than develop one for nhibernate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are some problems mixing NHibernate and Sync Framework.

See [Sync Framework clashes with NHibernate when inserting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387034/microsoft-sync-framework-clashes-with-nhibernate-toomanyrowsaffectedexception). You'll see some workarounds in that post, but keep in mind they don't place nice together without some patching to the way you work with your data.