# Sync two SqlExpress using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am creating a simple project management system which uses NHibernate for object storage. The underlying database is SQL express (at least currently for development).

The client runs on either the desktop or laptop. I know I could use web-services and store the DB only on the desktop, but this would force the desktop to be available all the time.

I am currently thinking about duplicating the DB, having two instances with "different data". To clarify, we are not talking about a productive app here, its a prototype.

**One way to achieve this very simple would be the following process:**

- Client: Check if desktop DB is available (through web service)
- Client: If yes, use desktop storage, no problem here
- Client: If not, use own DB as storage
- Client: Poll desktop regulary, as soon as it comes on, sync
- Client: Switch to desktop storage
- ...
- Desktop: Do not attempt any DB operation before checking for required sync
- Desktop: If sync needed, do it...

My question is now, how would you sync? Assume 4 or 5 types of objects, all have GUID as identifiers. Would you always manually "lazy load" all objects of a certain type and feed them to the DB. Would you always drop the whole desktop DB in case the client DB may be newer and out of sync?

Again, I want to stress out, I am not assuming any conflicts or stale data, I basically just want to "copy the whole DB from the client". Would you use NHibernate for this? Or would you separate the copy process?

When I think about it, my questions comes down to this:

Is there any function from NHibernate:

**SyncDBs_SourceWins_(SourceDB, TargetDB)**

Thanks for help,
Chris

Comment: I think that replication can help you here but I'm not sure if SQL Express support replication

Comment: I could switch to SQL2008 professional. Talking about break a fly on a wheel :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not NHibernate, but how about [Sync Services for ADO.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb726002.aspx)?

-sa

Comment: Well, just took a short look. Not sure, but I don't think it can be used in combination with NHibernate. And I definitly need NHibernate (ok, want :-) Only this sync stuff just came up, for "convenience reasons"

Comment: No, it is not NHibernate, but it should be possible to use them side by side though it's definitely not best looking. A question about integrating both worlds here on so is yet unanswered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264161/does-nhibernate-intergrate-well-with-microsoft-sync-framework).

Besides, doing it manually is tedious. A long work and you will most definitely ran into some strange situations.

Comment: Ok, I will have a closer look on the sync framework. A little basic research can't hurt...